# Get rid of object properties not listed in union type

Tags: typescript

I assume this isn't possible in Typescript, but maybe I am wrong so here is my question:

Assume a I have an object, for example

```js
const person = {
  name: "Feter Pox",
  city: "Berlin",
  age: "30",
};
```

this is just a plain object but I can change it to whatever is needed to solve the problem, as long as accessing `name` yields `Feter Pox` etc.

Now, I also have a union type, such as:

```js
type keys = 'name' | 'age';
```

It is important to note that, this cannot be changed. The problem below could be solved turning the `array` `['name', 'age']` into the `keys` type and working from there, but there is no such `array`.

**Problem:** Create a copy of `person` (`reducedPerson`) with all keys listed in `keys`. Any key not listed in `keys` should not exist on the object.

Expected result:

```js
const reducedPerson = {
  name: "Feter Pox",
  age: "30",
};
```

My approach, obviously doesn't work:

```js
const person = {
  name: "Feter Pox",
  city: "Berlin",
  age: "30",
};

type keys = 'name' | 'age';

const reducedPerson: Record<keys, string> = person;

reducedPerson. // GOOD: 'name' and 'age' autocomplete, 'city' not suggested for autocomplete

console.log(reducedPerson); // BAD: 'city' still in object
```

Comment: You cannot use type information (compile time only) to change actual behavior (run time). You would have to create the array of of keys yourself (although you could probably at least ensure that the values match the `keys` type).

Comment: "there is no such array"... so make one?  TypeScript's type system is completely erased when the code is compiled to JavaScript so there's no `keys` type to act on (I'd call this `Keys` to be conventional).  Is there a reason you can't create the array you need or the equivalent runtime data structure?

Comment: This was an overly trivialized example. The type is, in reality, the result of a computation, such as `type keys = MakeT<T>`. I understand that types are removed for runtime but it makes no sense to me why compile time stuff (I mean this information is just there right in front of your eyes) can't be made available to the runtime. When `type keys = 'name' | 'age';` then why is there no tool to turn this into an array `['name', 'age']`... :((

Comment: Why not do the opposite and derive `keys` from a runtime array (using `as const`)?